# Python Decrement Dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

can I decrement a value in a dictionary ? I have a dict with string key and int value, how to decrement all value's key ?

```
d={'A': 0, 'B' : 1, 'C' : 2, 'D' : 3}
d.pop('B')
##How to decrement values after 'B' ?
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "After 'B'"? What version of python is this?

Comment: "Increment all values after B", dictionaries are unsorted in some versions of python.  How do we know which values come after B?

Comment: Version is 3.6.5 , when I delete 'B' , I have to decrement  'C' and 'D'

Comment: Do you want to decrement the keys that are _alphabetically_ after "B"?

Comment: I have a dict where keys are name , and values are ID ...  Maybe it's better to reverse things?

Comment: No, I want decrement value of alphabetical key

Comment: Well we don't really know what you're trying to achieve. Keys must be immutable so it's unlikely that you want to reverse the dictionary.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that 'after B' means the keys lexicographically following 'B' in this case, this snippet should work:

```
d={'A': 0, 'B' : 1, 'C' : 2, 'D' : 3}
d.pop('B')
for k in d.keys():
    if k > 'B':
        d[k] -= 1
```

Comment: `for k in d` iterates over the keys.

Comment: I thought this might be a little clearer for this instance but you're right DyZ

Comment: Also, any reason to use `dict.pop` instead of `del d['B']`? We aren't storing the value returned.

Comment: Only that I copied the first two lines from the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
d={'A': 0, 'B' : 1, 'C' : 2, 'D' : 3}
e={'dfg': 3, 'dec': 2, 'aaa': 0, 'cbbb': 1}


def remElem(l, i):
    del l[i]
    [l.update({k: v-1}) for k, v in l.items() if k > i]


print(d)
remElem(d, 'B')
print(d)

print(e)
remElem(e, 'cbbb')
print(e)
```

Gives:

```
{'A': 0, 'C': 2, 'B': 1, 'D': 3}
{'A': 0, 'C': 1, 'D': 2}

{'dfg': 3, 'dec': 2, 'aaa': 0, 'cbbb': 1}
{'dfg': 2, 'dec': 1, 'aaa': 0}
```

Comment: Why iterate over items if you don't use the value? Surely better to just iterate over keys?

Comment: It works ! But wait, In dictionary I have names not single character .. `if  k > i: ` decrement in alphabetic way ?

Comment: see extra example